# React-reponsive carousel to fit parent container width and height

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am new to react.
I a trying to setup a little app. On home page we have carousel.
My home page code is:

```
render(){
        return (
            <div className="main-page">
                <div className="row full-height">
                    <div className="common-info col-lg-7">
                        <div className="row center-lg logo-container">
                            <LogoImg/>
                        </div>
                        <CarouselComponent/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-form col-lg-5">
                        <div className="justify-content-end">
          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

In scss:
I set up

```
.main-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Everything works fine until adding
 with

```
return (
            <div className="carousel-outer">
            <Carousel showArrows={true} showThumbs={false} showStatus={false}>
                <div>
                    <p className="row center-lg learn-eng white-text">Выучи английский</p>
                    <p className="row center-lg easy-fast white-text">Легко и быстро!</p>
                    <p className="row center-lg go-abroad white-text">Для поездок за границу</p>
                    <img src={vacation}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/2.jpeg"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/3.jpeg"/>
                </div>
            </Carousel>
            </div>
        );
```

I tried to add styles to Carousel:

```
.carousel .carousel-slider {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-style {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

But images are still outside parent container. Horizontal an vertical scrolls are there:
[image: Current display]

How can I fix the issue?
**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: use bootstrap?if true add `container` class side `main-page`

Comment: No, I decided that bootstrap is too heavy. Use only http://flexboxgrid.com/ library

Comment: ok.if can display sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) .it's great.

Comment: I have done it, but I can't check it on large screen that's strange https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-morse-sqsej

Comment: follow this [link](http://play.min.io/16oct/Capture.PNG?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F%2F20201016%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201016T123957Z&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bb2e6a961395c3a82b1a6273312f9aa6a0a5c4ed5066658437f3480104c7fcd8).for full display.ok.I try

Answer (score 0):

I could not modify your project but I made a sample .

tip:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .carousel .slide img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: auto; /*100vw*/
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]